# Jquery update to 3.1.1 -> Anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

To implement a library I had to upgrade JQuery to its 3.1.1 version.

It went pretty well despite a few deprecated functions easily fixed with some researches,
but one small script I am using on my website isn't working anymore and my JS knowledges are not that good.
The script in question is CountrySelect (it displays country names/flags inside an input list), here are the errors I am getting in my console :

> r.fn.load @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous function) @ countrySelect.js:32
>
> (anonymous function) @ countrySelect.js:8
>
> (anonymous function) @ countrySelect.js:10

and here are the 34 first lines of the script :

```
// wrap in UMD - see https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/jqueryPlugin.js
(function(factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([ "jquery" ], function($) {
            factory($, window, document);
        });
    } else {
        factory(jQuery, window, document);  // <------ LINE 8
    }
})(function($, window, document, undefined) {  // <------ LINE 10
    "use strict";
    var pluginName = "countrySelect", id = 1, // give each instance its own ID for namespaced event handling
    defaults = {
        // Default country
        defaultCountry: "",
        // Position the selected flag inside or outside of the input
        defaultStyling: "inside",
        // Display only these countries
        onlyCountries: [],
        // The countries at the top of the list. Defaults to United States and United Kingdom
        preferredCountries: [ "fr", "us", "gb", "ru", "cn" ]
    }, keys = {
        UP: 38,
        DOWN: 40,
        ENTER: 13,
        ESC: 27,
        PLUS: 43,
        A: 65,
        Z: 90
    }, windowLoaded = false;
    // keep track of if the window.load event has fired as impossible to check after the fact
    $(window).load(function() {  // <------ LINE 32
        windowLoaded = true;
    });
```

I would really appreciate some help to understand why it is not working anymore, I can't figure it out so far. How should I fix this ?

Comment: what is the actual error? javascript usually outputs what the error is, not just "where" it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.load()` method has been removed in jQuery 3. replace line 32 with the following code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {  // <------ LINE 32
  windowLoaded = true;
});
```

Source: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed

Comment: Indeed that was it... So it was a deprecated function after all ? I thought removed function would show up in my console as such (like some others I had when upgrading to 3.1.1) with something else than "anonymous function". Thanks for your answer, this is working just fine now :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether there were deprecation warnings for this change in previous jQuery versions, but in this case the actual method does not exist anymore. That also means that it's not possible to catch the call and show a message in response. Glad I could help you out.